# Why spark sketch BloomFilter slow and has high false positives rate

Tags: apache-spark, bloom-filter

I'm using spark (2.3 version) with sketch bloom filter

```
val tbl = spark.table(table)
  .where(whereCond)
  .select("request_id").cache()  // request_id is tring type

val numItems = tbl.count
val errRate = 0.01
val bfDF = tbl.stat.bloomFilter("request_id", numItems, errRate)

val bf = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(bfDF) 

myOtherDF.map{ data =>
  ....
  val exists = bf.value.mightContainString(data.req_id)
}
```

The ~ number of rows that will be inserted into BF is ~ 350,000,000

Running this I'm getting a too high number of false positives ~ 90%  - so it actually doesn't work correctly
And the performance of this step is very very slow takes ~ 1.5 minutes (only the BloomFilter creation)

Does it known to be wrong with large numbers, and why is that so sloooow ?

Comment: 1.5 for a distributed job doesn't sound particularly slow, but it is not possible to tell more without additional details (cluster size, number tasks, inputs). As of FP rate - one you pass to filter is FP-rate on training set. FP-rate can differ highly out-of-sample, for example if new data has much higher cardinality (but there are other possible failure scenarios).

Comment: Thanks, and if I provide a higher number of numItems that it is in actual df, can this impact on errRate?

Comment: When creating a Bloom Filter, the size required is calculated based on the expected number of items to be inserted. This calculation aims to have the filter at 50% fill-rate when full. Inserting items beyond this number will increase the fill-rate and with it, the error-rate.

Comment: That's exacetly what I had, when skiped count step at the begining

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Spark implementation of Bloom Filters so I can't tell you what you are doing wrong but from what you wrote and from your results it seems you have inserted more items than the filter was created for.

This will increase the fill-rate which explains your high error-rate.
High fill-rate also means the filter takes longer to return a false answer. With 50% fill-rate, on average the filter checks 2 locations before returning FALSE. Obviously, in your case (90% errRate) most items require checking all 7 bits (errRate=0.01) which might explain the slow operation.